# Using Map/Reduce/Filter on R Data Frame

Tags: r

I have a large data-frame in R (several thousand columns and rows). I need to add a new column to it and write the same file name into each row of the column, so that when I combine several data frames later, I can know from which files the rows were sources.

I am currently doing something like this:

```
# assume `filename` contains the path of a file
rows_with_filename <- rep(filename, nrow(my_data_frame)
result <- cbind (rows_with_filename, my_data_frame)
```

I was thinking that this might not be the most efficient way to do this and I tried rewriting it using the Map function. I came up with this solution but it does not work:

```
result <- Map(function(row) { return (c(filename, row)) }, my_data_frame)
```

This does not work, because (I think) it maps over the columns of the frame and not over its rows.

How can I fix this to map over the rows of the dataframe? Also would this really be faster then using `rep` and `cbind`

Comment: To write a single filename to one column of a data.frame you don't need `rep` - just assign the value to the whole column and it'll be recycled.

Comment: What about just `my_data_frame$result <- "filename"`?

Comment: Also, consider putting those data.frames into a *named* list and then using tools like `data.table::rbindlist(my_list, id = "filename")`.

Comment: @Jaap It seems your example requires that there exists already a column named `result` in `my_data_frame`, right? But I want to prepend a new column to the data set which does not exist yet.

Comment: no, @Jaap s solution generates the column and fills it with default value "filename" in one fell swoop. The column does get appended, not prepended, but you can always reorder the variables if that is important to you.